# LOAD DATA is not allowed in stored procedures

Tags: mysql, database, events, scheduled-tasks

I have a case to import data into mysql automatically every 6pm. data to be imported is "data.txt".

I created in mysql like this:

```
CREATE EVENT EVENT_NAME
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '18: 00:00 'DAY
DO
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'd :/ data.txt'
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS terminated BY ','
LINES terminated BY '\ n'
(atribut1, atribut2, atribut3);
```

if i just write like this

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'd :/ data.txt'
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS terminated BY ','
LINES terminated BY '\ n'
(atribut1, atribut2, atribut3);
```

the query was successfully executed

but if i write the code like a fist code instead there is an error "LOAD DATA is not allowed in stored procedures". is it really like that? if it's like that how do i to handle such cases? thanks in advance
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, [you are out of luck](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).

You will need to resort to an external mechanism in order to automate this import (such as a cron job).

You can submit arbitrary statements from outside MySQL by calling the `mysql` command-line client like this:

```
    shell > mysql [options] -D [database] -e "LOAD DATA INFILE..."
```

Comment: This -e command doesn't work anymore. :\ I'm using Powershell and all it does is spit out the manual.

Comment: @ihodonald I think you got confused, perhaps you meant to downvote yourself? [Are you even using MySQL at all](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute)? Oh well, if that makes you feel better, suit yourself.

Comment: after doing some research, I actually found out that your answer is specific to the Linux operating system. In my case, I created a scheduled task. Spicy.

Comment: In Windows (Powershell), you have to be explicit. `--execute`. Also, saying "you are out of luck" doesn't answer the question.