# Automatically load mysql database from CSV files

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv

How to load the mysql database from csv files on schedule automatically? Currently my server don't allow me to use mysql trigger to load data which pose an error

> Load data is not allowed in stored procedure.

Can i use mysql to execute a command to php that will reload the data from csv?
If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273030/load-data-is-not-allowed-in-stored-procedures

Comment: and to automate use `cronjob`